# How to import Jackson Core JacksonFactory using NetBeans?

Tags: java, gradle, import, netbeans, jackson

***do see the linked question for a fixed import statement.  I'll be updating this question after trying from Netbeans.***

---

With Netbeans being used below, everything [should build](https://github.com/NICKSAUNDERS/sheets).  However, this question is meant to be specific to Netbeans.

*Looking for Netbeans to add the requisite import statements.*

The specific missing import:

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory.html

code:

```
package sheets;

public class App {

    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS, SheetsScopes.DRIVE, SheetsScopes.DRIVE_FILE);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new App().getGreeting());
    }
}
```

cannot resolve or find all imports:

[image: import]

above, enough of the imports are found to suggest that other imports should be available -- **but not all**.

build file:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the 'Building Java & JVM projects' chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/building_java_projects.html
 * This project uses @Incubating APIs which are subject to change.
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client
    // implementation group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client', version: '1.34.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client
    implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '2.2.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty
    implementation group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-jetty', version: '1.34.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-sheets
    implementation group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-sheets', version: 'v4-rev612-1.25.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.15.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client-jackson2
    implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-jackson2', version: '1.20.0'


}

testing {
    suites {
        // Configure the built-in test suite
        test {
            // Use TestNG test framework
            useTestNG('7.5')
        }
    }
}

// Apply a specific Java toolchain to ease working on different environments.
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(20)
    }
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'sheets.App'
}
```

**this question is intended to be NetBeans specific.**

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to "reload project"(in the context menu)?

Comment: yes, I and I've also closed the project.  From the CLI the gradle build fails as at the end of the question still, however.  Perhaps the build file is lacking in some way.  Pardon the lengthy question.

Comment: @NicholasSaunders what netbeans version do you use? As I see it works when you added import manually for JsonFac, so it seems there's a problem with integration between ide and gradle

Comment: Oh, I don't see that it works at all so I don't understand your answer.  The cli build is still failing when the import is added manually, indicating that requisite JAR files cannot be located for the import statement.  No?

Comment: @NicholasSaunders You provided 2 code versions(one with no imports at all and one with 3 imports you added manually) and error traces to both of them. First version have 7 errors, second version have 4 errors(imports works). You can solve the issue by adding imports manually, but as I understand you want NetBeans to resolve imports for you?(but somewhy ide don't see JARs). So that's why I ask what NetBeans version do you use

Comment: I can remove the console build, if that helps.  The reason I included having the import statement typed manually was to demonstrate that the requisite package was still missing.  That is:  whether the import statement is written or not still results in an error.

Comment: @NicholasSaunders lol, but there less errors when you added imports manually. Could you try to resolve all the imports manually and tell me if errors still persist please?

Comment: @ArtemLisun You stated that you had tried the solution proposed here (_"reload project"_), yet you still accepted this answer. Can you clarify why you accepted it if it did not resolve your issue? And what was the actual resolution to your problem if reloading/reopening the project didn't work? It looks as though your problem may have got resolved through comments which is not helpful to the SO community.

Comment: I'm trying to simplify this question, so allow me edit it a bit pls.