# How to configure the build path, JDK and JRE for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, build, ide

From the bash console, [this hello world project](https://github.com/NICKSAUNDERS/sheets) builds with gradle fine.  However, [the IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76547949/4531180) shows:

[image: build path]

clicking on line 1 gives:

> Configure build path...
>
> Open the Java build path properties of project 'app'

Again, [builds fine from the console](https://github.com/NICKSAUNDERS/sheets/blob/main/app/build.gradle) with gradle:

(too long, see above link for the build file.)

system info:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ snap info eclipse
name:      eclipse
summary:   Extensible Tool Platform and Java IDE
publisher: Snapcrafters✪
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/eclipse
contact:   https://github.com/snapcrafters/eclipse/issues
license:   unset
description: |
  Eclipse provides IDEs and platforms for nearly every language and architecture. We are famous for
  our Java IDE, C/C++, JavaScript and PHP IDEs built on extensible platforms for creating desktop,
  Web and cloud IDEs. These platforms deliver the most extensive collection of add-on tools
  available for software developers.
  
  This snap is maintained by the Snapcrafters community, and is not necessarily endorsed or
  officially maintained by the upstream developers.
commands:
  - eclipse
snap-id:      QzFGHW76hR3cZjpcuHt4sAjj5KZbd05T
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: today at 14:20 PDT
channels:
  latest/stable:    2022-12 2023-06-16 (67) 329MB classic
  latest/candidate: 2023-03 2023-06-16 (68) 333MB classic
  latest/beta:      ↑                             
  latest/edge:      2023-03 2023-06-16 (69) 333MB classic
installed:          2022-12            (67) 329MB classic
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-04-21 12:31:26 UTC
Revision:     1cf537a851c635c364a4214885f8b9798051175b

Kotlin:       1.8.10
Groovy:       3.0.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          20.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 20.0.1+9-29)
OS:           Linux 5.19.0-45-generic amd64

nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ javac --version
javac 20.0.1
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ java --version
java 20.0.1 2023-04-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.1+9-29, mixed mode, sharing)
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

screenshots:

[image: a]

[image: b]

error message:

[image: error1]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the other error messages? What have you already tried? Can you expand the Project and External Dependencies node? It's probably very relevant.

Comment: Which is the exact error message of the root problem shown in the _Problems_ view? Also you should always provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your linked `build.gradle` you set Java 20 to be used in your project, but maybe you missed to configured a Java 20 JRE/JDK in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: I don't know how to expand the Project and External Dependencies node @nitind

Comment: added the exact error message @howlger and get the gist of what you're suggesting but am not entirely familiar with Eclipse and finding those specific configurations.  Looking for Installed JRE's.  (On the system the javac and java --version commands are shown).

Comment: the linked sample code @howlger is quite minimal -- not sure how it could be further pared down.  As it's on git, should be reproducible, yes?  If there's better sample code for this purpose, totally open -- but that code is as bare-bones as it gets.

Comment: Make sure your Eclipse is up to date (2023-06), and also make sure in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_ a Java 20 JDK is configured: see [e.g. my video](https://youtu.be/OQe_hafeuz8).