# How to add the Jackson JsonFactory to the classpath using Gradle?

Tags: java, json, gradle, import, classpath

For the [sake of clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76547949/4531180) have removed any IDE's from the mix, and just trying to build and run a [simple app](https://github.com/NICKSAUNDERS/sheets) using Jackson.

This question is intended to be independent of any IDE or any other Java technologies, using just the java and javac commands from gradle.  In that sense it's quite minimal.  As minimal as possible.

```
nicholas@mordor:~/json$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/json$ git clone git@github.com:NICKSAUNDERS/sheets.git
Cloning into 'sheets'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 61, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (61/61), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (39/39), done.
remote: Total 61 (delta 12), reused 51 (delta 6), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (61/61), 23.22 KiB | 448.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (12/12), done.
nicholas@mordor:~/json$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/json$ cd sheets/
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ tree
.
├── app
│   ├── bin
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   └── java
│       │       └── sheets
│       │           └── App.java
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── sheets
│                   └── AppTest.java
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── settings.gradle

11 directories, 10 files
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ gradle run

> Task :app:compileJava FAILED
/home/nicholas/json/sheets/app/src/main/java/sheets/App.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable JacksonFactory
  location: class App
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 945ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ cat app/build.gradle 
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the 'Building Java & JVM projects' chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/building_java_projects.html
 * This project uses @Incubating APIs which are subject to change.
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client
    // implementation group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client', version: '1.34.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client
    implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '2.2.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty
    implementation group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-jetty', version: '1.34.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-sheets
    implementation group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-sheets', version: 'v4-rev612-1.25.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.15.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client-jackson2
    implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-jackson2', version: '1.20.0'




}

testing {
    suites {
        // Configure the built-in test suite
        test {
            // Use TestNG test framework
            useTestNG('7.5')
        }
    }
}

// Apply a specific Java toolchain to ease working on different environments.
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(20)
    }
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'sheets.App'
}
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ cat app/src/main/java/sheets/App.java 
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package sheets;

import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;

public class App {

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new App().getGreeting());
    }
}
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ java --version
java 20.0.1 2023-04-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.1+9-29, mixed mode, sharing)
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ javac --version
javac 20.0.1
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-04-21 12:31:26 UTC
Revision:     1cf537a851c635c364a4214885f8b9798051175b

Kotlin:       1.8.10
Groovy:       3.0.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          20.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 20.0.1+9-29)
OS:           Linux 5.19.0-45-generic amd64

nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~/json/sheets$
```

So far as I can tell, the above gradle build file indeed includes Jackson and so the JacksonFactory should be available for the build.  How can the build file be fixed so that the import statement will work with the library on the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

wrong import statement above:

```
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package sheets;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;

public class App {

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";
 //   private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    public String getGreeting() {

    try {
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(new File("employee.txt"));
    } 
    catch (IOException e){}

        return "Hello World!";




    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new App().getGreeting());
    }
}
```

works.

Not sure how JsonParser relates to JsonFactory, and the sample code I was looking at didn't use the JsonParser that I recall.

In fact, it's quite different usage.  However, that's small potatoes as the objective was just to get a clean build with no compile errors.